# Validate URL path for several controller methods

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Given multiple REST resources to gather order information.

- `/order/{id}`
- `/order/{id}/positions`
- `/order/{id}/invoice`
- `/order/{id}/shipment`

Within the a Srping Boot 2 application it's implemented across multiple controllers, e.g. `OrderController`, `InvoiceController`, etc.

Currently every controller uses the OrderRepository to ensure the the order with the given `id` exists. Otherwise it throws an exception. It's always the same replicated code.

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {
    // ...
    @GetMapping("order/{id}")
    public Order getCustomer(@PathVariable final Integer id) {
        return this.orderRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("order not found"));
    }
}
```

Does the framework provide a callback to write the order `id` check just once?

---

I found the [`AntPathMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) but it seems not the right way, since it provides just an boolean interface.

Comment: Aren't you going to need that specific `Order` in each of those mappings? Why don't you put the `orderRepository.findById(..).orElseThrow(..)` in a separate method and call it for each method?

Comment: @g00glen00b I do not neet the order in every case. Calling specific method to ensure the validation is the current implementation. But you could forget the call when creating a new method which starts with `/order/{id}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually a good case for [bean validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation). While there is already builtin support for many cases of validation (`@Size`, `@NotNull`, ...), you can also write your own custom constraints.

First of all, you need to define an annotation to validate your ID, for example:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = OrderIdValidator.class)
@Target({PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidOrderId {
    String message() default "Invalid order ID";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Since your order ID is always a parameter for your controller mappings, you could use `ElementType.PARAMETER` to only allow the annotation for method parameters.

The next step is to add the `@Constraint` annotation to it and point to a custom validator class (eg. `OrderIdValidator`):

```
@Component
public class OrderIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidOrderId, Integer> {
    private OrderRepository repository;

    public OrderIdValidator(OrderRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer id, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return repository.existsById(id);
    }
}
```

By implementing the `isValid` method, you can check whether or not the order exists. If it doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown and the `message()` property of the `@ValidOrderId` annotation will be used as a message.

The last step is to add the `@Validated` annotation to all of your controllers, and to add the `@ValidOrderId` annotation to all order ID parameters, for example:

```
@Validated // Add this
@RestController
public class OrderController {
    @GetMapping("order/{id}")
    public Order getCustomer(@PathVariable @ValidOrderId final Integer id) { // Add @ValidOrderId
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

---

If you prefer to use a different response status for your validations, you could always add a class annotated with the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation and use the following method:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void handleConstraints(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
}
```